# Data Version Control with Google Drive Remote: "googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: drive version: v2"

Tags: google-client, dvc

I'm trying to setup DVC with Google Drive storage as shown [here](https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/setup-google-drive-remote#url-format). So far, I've been unsuccessful in pushing data to the remote. I tried both with and without the Google App setup.

After running a `dvc push -v`, the following exception is shown:

```
  File "(...)/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/googleapiclient/discovery.py", line 387, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    raise UnknownApiNameOrVersion("name: %s  version: %s" % (serviceName, version))
googleapiclient.errors.UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: drive  version: v2
```

DVC was installed via `pip install dvc[gdrive]`. The `pip freeze` of the concerning packages is:

```
oauth2client==4.1.3
google-api-python-client==2.0.1
dvc==2.0.1
```

Any help is thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try to install `google-api-python-client==1.12.8` and test in that way?

Edit:

It appears to be that, this was a bug in the 2.0.0-2.0.1 of google-api-client and resolved in 2.0.2. So this should also work `google-api-python-client>=2.0.2`

Comment: See also https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/5618 for a similar issue with packages based on [`pyinstaller`](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) like [dvc_2.0.5_amd64.deb](https://github.com/iterative/dvc/releases/download/2.0.5/dvc_2.0.5_amd64.deb).